How to use Classes and their getters in Pinia store?
I have defined a Pinia store in which my user's character is made, stored/retrieved from localStorage, and pushed into an array which the store eventually returns.
This is done by defining the class Character, in which the character's name, level, and so on is defined.
The problem: some of the values of that class are getters or (computed()=>{...}), which don't fire after the characters array is imported and stored to refs in a component.
I've tried working with both getters and computed values (one of which wraps this in a nested scope, causing problems when referencing other values in the class). I've left this in the sample below, but commented for your context.
I've also migrated all these computed values into a separate function instantiate_characters() that is called whenever the app is loaded, after all characters have been loaded. This works, but I consider it a dirty workaround. I'd much rather just create a new object from a class and have it work dynamically.
Sample:
export const use_game_store = defineStore('game_store', () => {

    const characters = ref([])

    class Character {
        constructor(existing_character){
            // const this_character = this
            this.general = {
                name: existing_character ? existing_character.general.name : '',
                // get level(){
                //     let level = 0
                //     for (let c of this_character.general.classes){
                //         level += c.level
                //     }
                //     return level
                // },
                level: computed(()=>{
                    let level = 0
                    for (let c of this.general.classes){
                        level += c.level
                    }
                    return level
                }),
                classes: [
                    // an array with classes (e.g. Warrior), 
                    // each of which has its own level
                ]
            }
            this.attributes = {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        characters,
    }
})


I think it would help if you showed some of the code around. Like where you save the characters in refs. Also to summarize: You have a problem that the level (computed property) is not being adjusted after you add a class with its own levels for example?

Yeah, that's exactly it: every character has an array of classes, each of which have a level. If my warrior class goes from 4 to 5, and i already have a rogue class at 2, i expect my overall character-level to go from 6 to 7, for example.

Still it would be useful to see where and how you instantiate these classes and where and how you are adding classes to a character. I am absolutely not sure about this, but could it be, that within that Class we must have a different understanding of how reactivity works?
